# Secure download link (HTTPS) for Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 16.04, security, downloads, https

All the download links I see for Ubuntu 16.04 desktop are http links. Is there a secure (https) link anywhere?

Comment: This question has a [newer answer here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1063638/134479) that takes into account more recent (and more secure) measures to ensure that your copy of Ubuntu is verifiably authentic.

Comment: Reminder: HTTPS is not a procedure that can be called secure. It all depens on certificates and there have been lots of example where those got compromized. The download over http is good enough. What you DO should do is match the checksum after downloading.

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? The answers in the other thread does not answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

The full list of Ubuntu CD images mirrors is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors). Some of them support HTTPS, although you may have to add the *s* manually.