# Secure Download (HTTPS) for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: security

I know this a similare question was already asked in 2016 but I feel that the answer is quite insufficient:
[Secure download link (HTTPS) for Ubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805943/secure-download-link-https-for-ubuntu-desktop)

There should be very clear path to securely acquire ubuntu instead of the now default of downloading it from http source.

Even MD5 checksums for the images are only accessible through http. Torrent link, same problem.

Maybe I am missing something, but it really looks like there is no way of getting a proper ubuntu copy securely.

Even with https mirrors, without a secure way of getting the MD5 from canonical, how can we trust that the image has not been tampered with?

Comment: See the official guide: [How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Comment: Or How-to Geek: [How to Verify a Linux ISO’s Checksum and Confirm It Hasn’t Been Tampered With](https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/)

Comment: It sounds like you should open a bug in Launchpad against Ubuntu about the HTTP not being automatic redirect to HTTPS perhaps?

Comment: HTTPS isn't enough for security of your operating system installer. This is because if someone hacks into the web server and puts a bad ISO there, the server will happily send it to you via HTTPS. It's much more difficult to steal Canonical's GPG signing keys, so follow others' advice here and use that to verify your download when it's done. This has a side benefit of making sure that the download wasn't accidentally corrupted in a way that HTTPS and TCP and so on can't detect.

Comment: @wjandrea that guide is wrong. It assumes that your internet connection (i.e. the connection from your place to the server) hasn't been tampered with. In the case of a man in the middle attack, you won't be able to tell a legit Ubuntu iso from a corrupted one. There is conceptually no way to be sure that the installation medium is legit unless you obtain it from the developer directly, and even then, you'll have to trust the guy you are talking to.

Comment: @danzel have you actually _read_ the guide that wjandrea is referring to? It explains, in easy to follow steps, everything up to obtaining the Ubuntu GPG key and verifying the authenticity of the signed MD5 and SHA keys. Also note that kernel images are signed (see [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063644/134479)), thus providing a second, independent chain of trust. _Of course_ there is "conceptually no way to be sure" of anything, but the OP was not asking for the non-existent concept of "perfect security", nor did wjandrea claim that that guide provides it.

Comment: Above all, the guide itself does not claim that it provides absolute security, so your claim that the guide "is wrong", is itself wrong as it's based on a strawman argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Ubuntu images come with MD5 and SHA256 checksums.  The checksum files are GPG signed with an Ubuntu public key.  The public key is obtained verifiably from the Ubuntu keyserver.  Easy-to-follow instructions are in [How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu).

To add to this, the binary images are signed by the Canonical Master CA, which has a chain of trust to a certificate in your machine's TPM, and will not run if tampered with and you run under SecureBoot.

Short of hopping on your bike and having the people at Ubuntu burn a fresh image while you watch them, I think this really is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily download ubuntu desktop from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

After downloading, you can verify the downloaded ISO using this turtorial (refered at the bottom of the download page): https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: Even though the link you provide to the download page is using HTTPS, the actual download will *not* be done over HTTPS but from e.g. http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.3/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso